# "Type is not defined" error on project build

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I created a new VB.net windows applications project and added a reference to my utilities project like I have done many times before. When I start coding, the editor will find the utility namespace without difficulty but when I build I get "Type My.Utils.Data is not defined".

I've compared my project to my other projects and can't find a difference.

When I try to debug, I get a dialog saying "Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target "C:.....\myproject.exe" is missing

Comment: Are they targeting different versions of the framework, by any chance?

Comment: That was it! It was using the client profile.

Comment: You're just lucky that I had this exact same problem not two days ago :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to make sure that the consuming project is targeting a .NET Framework version which is equal to or higher than the other project that it is referencing.  If the referenced project is targeting a higher version of the framework, Visual Studio will not give you a useful message like, "Wrong Framework Version".  Instead, it gives you a very confusing error about the assembly being missing, even though it's there.

Comment: Nailed it! Worked for me. Just had to update the project to the same target framework version as the projects it was referencing.

Comment: Yeah!!!. This was the issue for me as well, the trouble was, I had to update all the applications even though the DLL is referenced in only in one application as the referenced application DLL is used in my other projects :)

Comment: ahhh VS is not intuitive, had a project mismatch (4.0 referencing a 4.7.1 project). Worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error and had a more unusual root cause. I'll add it here because someone may experience the same. (I don't expect this to be the "normal" cause of this error.)  Anyway, I created a service reference and I removed the text "Reference" from the name of it and called it "ServiceName" rather than "ServiceNameReference. Apparently that created a naming conflict that blew up the reference.vb file.